# Phonegap - Image URL wrong from camera when sending through filetransfer?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

So It appears that I have stumbled across a very bizarre issue with phonegap 2.2.0.

I am trying to take a picture, and send it through the filetransfer plugin, like so:

```
if(navigator.camera) {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(function(imageURI){
            console.log('captured image = '+imageURI);
            $('#photoConfirmation .image-preview').attr('src', imageURI);
            self.photoURI = imageURI;
            $('#photoConfirmation').show().simpledialog2({
                'mode' : 'bool',
                'prompt' : '',
                'useModal': true,
                'zindex':1001,                    
                'callbackClose': function(e){
                    $('#photoConfirmation').hide();
                }
            });
        }, 
        function(message){
            alert('Failed to get picture: ' + message);
        }, {
            sourceType:1, 
            quality: 50, 
            destinationType:1
        });
    } else {
        alert('Camera is not supported on this device.');
    }    

 var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey="files[]";
    options.fileName = 'image_something'.jpg';
    options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
    options.chunkedMode = false;

    var params = new Object();
    params.extraData= 'object-' + anObject.id;

    options.params = params;
    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(imageURI, "http://someupload.com/destination/url", function(r){alert('Finished upload!');}, function(error){console.log(error);alert('Error uploading image with code: ' +error.code)}, options);
```

The problem is, this shows up in the preview, but does not upload!  The picture is definitely getting captured because I see it in the image preview... I could've sworn I did something like this before.  Does anyone see anything that I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a reference implementation of the FileTransfer plugin (which uses the captured photo from a camera) on the [Cordova API Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer), which many differences in it's implementation from yours.  Reading though your code it looks like you are firing off a File Transfer before you capture the photo (and create the imageURI).  Also you are using numerical constants for `sourceType` and `destinationType`.  Though these are most likly not causing the problem you are experiencing, the correct forms for these is:

```
destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
```

Here is an example with some small typo fixes (I'm assuming that extra `'` in the fileName isn't a part of your code) of what should be a working version:

```
if (navigator.camera) {
  navigator.camera.getPicture(

  function (imageURI) {
    console.log('captured image = ' + imageURI);
    $('#photoConfirmation .image-preview').attr('src', imageURI);
    self.photoURI = imageURI;
    $('#photoConfirmation').show().simpledialog2({
      'mode': 'bool',
      'prompt': '',
      'useModal': true,
      'zindex': 1001,
      'callbackClose': function (e) {
        $('#photoConfirmation').hide();
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey = "files[]";
        options.fileName = 'image_something.jpg';
        options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
        options.chunkedMode = false;
        var params = new Object();
        params.extraData = 'object - ' + anObject.id;
        options.params = params;
        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(imageURI, "http://someupload.com/destination/url", function (r) {
          alert('Finished upload!');
        }, function (error) {
          console.log(error);
          alert('Error uploading image with code: ' + error.code)
        }, options);
      }
    });
  },

  function (message) {
    alert('Failed to get picture: ' + message);
  }, {
    sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    quality: 50,
    destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
  });
} else {
  alert('Camera is not supported on this device.');
}
```

Comment: You're right.  In this particular implementation.  I was trying to abstract the rest of the unnecessary code and only show what was needed.  In my actual code, they don't fire simultaneously, they are in order...

Comment: It might be confusing for others who are trying to help to use your code sample as a guide.  Can you perhaps boil it down to a running (or not running) sample of what you are talking about?